# Python tool to check all function usages within project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a vague memory of this question being asked before somewhere in cyberspace but I can't find it again.

Say I have a file with a bunch of functions (and or classes) defined, but I know that some of them are not used anywhere in my project. Is there a tool to scan through my project to see which functions aren't being used?

I know I can do this individually for each function, using Pycharm for example, but I don't know of a way to do this for all functions in a file. It feels like there must be a tool for this, but I don't know of one.

**EDIT**

I know there are edge cases of code, as pointed out by @deceze, that make this sort of usage checking impossible in general. But I'd be happy with a tool that works 99% of the time. The rest can be caught by unit tests for example, and manually handled.

Comment: pylint? Something like defined but not used

Comment: Note that this is made virtually impossible by the fact that you could (as an extreme example) do `getattr(foo, input('Enter function name'))()`, which is impossible to trace with a static tool.

Comment: @deceze Yes I should have mentioned that I don't expect the tool to work 100% of the time, and that I'd be happy with it working on 99% of sane code. Of course there are insane edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any tool that explores your whole project but you could easily make one in few lines of code by using the [jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

There is [jedi.Script.usages](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/api.html#jedi.Script.usages) which is exactly what you want here, the tool would do something like:

- Create a jedi [environment](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/api.html#jedi.api.environment.Environment) using your python interpreter of choice (this way will have information about `sys.path`
- Walk over the project files you want to analize and extract the functions you want to check usages from (glob, os.walk, custom cli, ...)
- On each file, you just need to extract the functions you want to analize (in your parser you store the locations as line/columns pairs)
- Create a jedi script with the previous location and call usages and then store the results in a dictionary
- Profit

PS: the most "tricky" step would be the one that extract functions from your python files but I guess this could also be done with jedi instead using another builtin python parsers, here's an untested piece of code:

```
for definition in jedi.names(source, all_scopes=True, definitions=True, references=True):
    if definition.parent().type == "function": # The name is located in a function ...
        ass = definition.goto_assignments()
        if len(ass) > 0 and ass[0].parent().type == "function": # ... and is assigned to in a function
            print("Found a local variable:", definition.name)
```

Extracted from this github [issue](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/885)

Comment: Oh WOW, I had NEVER heard of Jedi (probably because I've been using Pycharm since the dawn of time). Looks interesting.

Comment: @Ray Highly recommended, I'm a SublimeText user but I can grant you a lot of IDEs out there use the awesome jedi library supporting autocompletion behind the curtains, it's a great library. Btw, edited my question... Good thing about this library is the public interface is really thin and you can build these sort of tools by yourself quite easily... give it a try! ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1a/) - used it recently to show my test coverage. But it can be used in other contexts as well